# AWS Deployment Failed due to "HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS"

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am working on a scenario, where I need to push the code from a GIT repository to AWS Instance. To achieve this I am using **AWS CodeDeploy** feature. But in the final step of the process to deploy the code, I am receiving the below error.

> Deployment Failed
>   The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see this error if the EC2 instance does not have the correct IAM role. Create an IAM role with the policy "AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy". You can't add an IAM role to an existing instance, so you'll have to launch a fresh one.

Also make sure you've installed the CodeDeploy agent for the correct region, e.g. for `us-east-1`:

```
apt-get -y install awscli ruby2.0
aws s3 cp s3://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest/install . --region us-east-1
chmod +x ./install
./install auto
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-set-up-new-instance.html

Comment: You can now attach/replace an IAM role on a running instance: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easily-replace-or-attach-an-iam-role-to-an-existing-ec2-instance-by-using-the-ec2-console/

Comment: from an answer below:

Just to add to @spro/@mathieu-m-gosselin 's answer, even though aws now allows to attach/replace an IAM role on a running instance but it is not enough for this use case , you have to reboot the instance after you attach/replace a new IAM role.

Share

Answer (score 5):

I repeatedly get same error from CodeDeploy tool, if I forget to install CodeDeploy agent to the instance. Just in case here is the link to the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-run-agent-install.html

Comment: Just to mention, that if you set the [user data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-add-user-data) after you have created the instance, the CodeDeploy agent won't be installed. You have to follow the instructions above to install it to your instance.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to @spro/@mathieu-m-gosselin 's answer, even though aws now allows to attach/replace an IAM role on a running instance but it is not enough for this use case , you have to reboot the instance after you attach/replace a new IAM role.

Comment: This should absolutely be part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate reason you get that error is when CodeDeploy cannot continue the deployment as too many instances is unhealthy. The "minimumHealthyHosts" plays a part in determining the exact number. You can check that parameter [1][2].

Having said that, for a start, it is easier if set that value to low (i.e. almost 0). Or select the "AllAtOnce" deployment config.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/get-deployment-config.html

[2] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/host-health.html

Comment: Hi Calvin, Thanks a lot for your quick response. Yes I have tried using the "AllAtOnce" deployment config. But still I get the above error. Also the current Instance is not connected to any IAM roles. So can this be one of the reasons?? If so how can we create a new IAM role and make it assigned to this Instance.

Comment: Yes, the EC2 instance must have permission to read the s3 bucket (if your artifact/package is stored there). First of all, create an IAM policy with the relevant s3:* permission to your bucket. Then, create the role (choose EC2 as the entity) and assign the policy created earlier. Next, specify the roles for instance profile when you launch a new EC2 machine.