# AWS deployment continuously failing due to "HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I already checked a couple of posts on StackOverflow before submitting this question. Even this post: [AWS Deployment Failed due to “HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143191/aws-deployment-failed-due-to-health-constraints)

After reading the above post, I checked the links provided and pasted that CodeDeploy Agent script in Deployment Configuration. I even added the proper CodeDeploy role to IAM as mentioned in the link.

Still the deployment is failing and giving the same "HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS" error.

What I am trying to achieve is that I have a .ZIP file in S3 bucket. This zip file contains a simple .html page and appspec.yml. This page needs to be installed to IIS [\Inetpub\wwwroot].

Answer (score 0):

The `HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS` constraints errors simply indicates that too many individual host deployments failed for the deployment to continue given your minimum healthy host setting. It's very generic, and it will not provide enough information for anybody to help you debug.

What you need to look at is the details for the individual host deployments that failed. If you click on `View Events` for a host that failed, you can see what step failed and it will likely include logs related to that failure. Once you have that information, you can troubleshoot the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

No healthy instance indicates that it is not able to deploy in ec2 or can't communicate with it. if this is the first deployment and failing in the instance check if AWS code deploy agent is running in the ec2 instance or not. use this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install.html

If you are facing this issue even though the code deploy agent is running, you can restart it to solve. YOu can also find logs in /var/log/aws/..

Thanks!